"The avatar must be an image" when trying to upload an image (.png)
I am trying to update a user's avatar, however I keep getting the error "The Avatar must be an image". But the update function on other part of the profile works like name email, etc..
I am really confuse on why it is not working? Any help would be highly appricated...
I am currently using livewire/livewire version 3.4, php version 8.2 and laravel/framework version 11.9, I have also did php artisan storage:link.
My code is bellow.
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class Users extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;
    public $users, $name, $email,
    $role, $avatar, $user_id,
    $currentAvatar = null;
    public $isOpen = false;

    public function render()
    {
        $this->users = User::all();
        return view('livewire.user', ['users' => User::all()])
        ->extends('layouts.app')
        ->section('content');
    }


    public function create()
    {
        $this->resetInputFields();
        $this->isOpen = !$this->isOpen;
        session()->flash('message', 'Create method triggered');
    }

    public function openModal()
    {
        $this->isOpen = true;
    }

    public function closeModal()
    {
        $this->isOpen = false;
    }

    private function resetInputFields()
    {
        $this->user_id = null;
        $this->name = '';
        $this->email = '';
        $this->role = 'student';  // Default role
        $this->avatar = null;

    }

     public function store()
     {
         $this->validate([
             'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
             'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,' . $this->user_id, 
             'role' => 'required|in:admin,lecturer,student',
             'avatar' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:1024',
         ]);

         $validatedData = [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'role' => $this->role,
        ];

         // Handle avatar upload(store file and save path)
         if ($this->avatar) {
            // Get file extension
            $extension = $this->avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();

            // Generate unique filename
            $filename = 'avatar-' . time() . '.' . $extension;

            // Store file publicly with custom filename
            $validatedData['avatar'] = $this->avatar->storePubliclyAs(path: 'avatars', name: $filename, disk: 'public');
        }

        // Using updateOrCreate to insert or update the user
        User::updateOrCreate(
            ['id' => $this->user_id],
            array_merge($validatedData, [
                'password' => $this->user_id
                    ? User::find($this->user_id)->password
                    : Hash::make('password'), // Default password for new users
            ])
        );

         session()->flash('message', $this->user_id ? 'User Updated Successfully.' : 'User created successfully.');
         $this->closeModal();
         $this->resetInputFields();
     }

    public function edit($id)
    {

        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        $this->user_id = $id;
        $this->name = $user->name;
        $this->email = $user->email;
        $this->role = $user->role;
        $this->currentAvatar = $user->avatar;

        $this->openModal();
        session()->flash('message', 'Edit method triggered');
    }
}

And part of the blade file, please note in my app.blade.php I have @livewireScripts in the body and @livewireStyle in head:
<div>
            <!-- Check if a new avatar file is uploaded and show its preview -->
            @if (!empty($currentAvatar))
                <img src="{{ Storage::url($currentAvatar) }}" class="mt-2" width="100" alt="Current Avatar" />

                <!-- If no avatar is uploaded or stored, show upload input and "No avatar uploaded" message -->
            @else
                <p>No avatar uploaded</p>
            @endif

            <!-- Input field for uploading an avatar -->
            <x-input-label for="avatar" :value="__('Avatar')" />
            <input wire:model.live="avatar" id="avatar" name="avatar" type="file" accept="image/*" class="mt-1 block w-full" />
            <x-input-error class="mt-2" :messages="$errors->get('avatar')" />
        </div>

Don't know if this helps, my schema for users:
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->enum('role', ['admin', 'lecturer', 'student'])->default('student');
            $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Also, here's my configuration:
    'disks' => [

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],
    ],

I have changed from the validation from 'avatar' => 'nullable|image|max:1024', to above to accept what I was trying to test (a .png with size 5.44 KB)
Originally, I didn't have $validatedData or array_merge as shown below:
 User::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->userId], [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'role' => $this->role,
            'avatar' => $this->avatar ? $this->avatar->store('avatars') : null,         
        ]);

and in edit function was $this->avatar = $user->avatar;
I discovered that the follwing was still not working and displayed "The avatar field must be an image." Despire update to above, it was still somehow stored in storage/app/private/livewire-tmp with random name CXZNomzyXgBbPLlHwQQNdXbZypmQ4y-metaTmV0U2F2dnkgTG9nbyAxIHcgZ3JhZGllbnQucG5n-.png instead of app/public with filenmae like avatar-1699458603.jpg
if ($this->avatar) {
    $validatedData['avatar'] = $this->avatar->store('avatars', 'public');
}

